# Authenticate a flask API with oauth?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-oauth

I'm creating a flask application on google App Engine. It's an API endpoint, which I only want users in my organization to be able to access. I have set up an oauth client that only allows users within my org, but I am unsure of the right way to require a token from this oauth client in my API requests.

I looked through the google docs and only saw tutorials for allowing auth onto a web page, ie: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web

Is there a recommended solution for authenticating an API call via oauth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Identity-Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/).